# Show that these 100 squares are the same color.

Tags: coloring

The squares of an infinite square graph paper are colored in 3 colors. Show that there exist 100 rows and 100 columns such that all squares in the intersections of the said columns (100 square) have the same color.
I am stuck the question is so ambiguous and that there are so many cases. Where do I start?

Comment: Try looking up the pigeonhole principle. It should help.

Comment: I know pigeonhole, but I;m not sure how to apply it.

Comment: Try first looking at a column, and proving that there must be at least infinitely many squares of some color. Then try extending your argument horizontally.

Comment: I think that since 100 isn't divisible by 3 somehow factors into the answer, but I am still stuck.

Comment: If there exist 100 columns and rows, then there also exists 99 columns and rows, and 99 is divisible by 3, so I am sure that does not factor into the answer. This can be solved for any finite $n$. You could also try doing the base case where $n=2$, then build up from there.

Comment: "the intersections of the said columns" how can columns intersect? Do you mean the intersection of the 100 columns with the 100 rows (which results in 10000 squares)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the colors are blue, green, and red.

Choose any row and a color that appears an infinite number of times in that row. Reduce the grid to only those columns that intersect the row with that color. Now we have an infinite grid with a monochromatic row, say the color is blue.

If blue now appears an infinite number of times in another row, repeat the process to get two blue rows. Similarly, if there then is a third row where blue appears infinitely many times, and so on. If we eventually find 100 blue rows then we can choose our monochromatic 100 by 100 blue box.

If not, then blue only appears finitely many times in every remaining row. There must be a color that appears infinitely many times in these rows, so choose a row and suppose green appears infinitely many times. Reduce to get a green row, etc. If we get to 100 green rows, we get a monochromatic 100 by 100 green box.

If not, then all remaining rows only contain a finite number of blue and green squares. Therefore, we can find a monochromatic 100 by 100 red box.